# iptables is converting the IP into a domain

Tags: iptables

I'd like to block an entire set of IPs on the server:

`iptables -A INPUT -s 77.0.0.0/8 -j DROP`

Though when I run

`iptables -L`

on that record I get a strange domain instead of the IP

```
DROP       tcp  --  x4d000000.dyn.telefonica.de/8  anywhere
```

Comment: Please, don't use images when you can use text.

Comment: You're blocking an entire `/8`? 0.5% of the entire IPv4 address space? That's a lot of collateral damage, if you're running a public service.

Comment: @MattNordhoff, I've checked and it's confined within a specific country. Yes, I want that as it is not a public service!

Comment: @Vinz thanks for the tip, I already approved the edit change

Comment: You are wrong in regards of only blocking 1 country with that range. Doing some random lookups on Ripe I found blocks in use in DE, DK, SE, PL and RO. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is normal, nothing to worry about move on and you should read the documentation.

You didn't specify `-n`

> -n, --numeric
>   Numeric output. IP addresses and port numbers will be printed in numeric format. By default, the program will try to display them as host names, network names, or services (whenever applicable).

so iptables tries it's best to provide a meaningful name. If you do a reverse lookup  on 77.0.0.0 the result will look familiar.

```
dig -x 77.0.0.0 +short
x4d000000.dyn.telefonica.de.
```

Answer (score 0):

I should simply have done:

```
iptables -L -n
```

Comment: You can get even more information about the rules by using `iptables-save`.

Comment: Self-answering a question is perfectly valid, but not if there is another answer which essentially says the same.

Comment: @glglgl I was just trying to synthesize, for further reading. I set the other answer as the correct solution

Comment: @joao_pimentel Then it should be ok!